# Image view in grid

Tags: android

I am trying to show an image from grid when we click on that.

```
package course.examples.UI.GridLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class GridLayoutActivity extends Activity {

protected static final String EXTRA_RES_ID = "POS";

private int[]  mThumbIdsFlowers = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
                R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4,     

                R.drawable.image5,
                R.drawable.image6, R.drawable.image7, R.drawable.image8,
                R.drawable.image9, R.drawable.image10, R.drawable.image11,
                R.drawable.image12};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String[] description = null;

    try
    {description=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.description);

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    GridView gridview=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, mThumbIdsFlowers,description));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(GridLayoutActivity.this,
                    ImageViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_RES_ID, (int) id);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

here is another activity

```
package course.examples.UI.GridLayout;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
public class ImageViewActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
imageView.setImageResource(intent.getIntExtra(GridLayoutActivity.EXTRA_RES_ID, 0));
    setContentView(imageView);
}
}
```

here I am trying to save the id in intent tag and accessing in another activity which will show the image.but on click image in GridView it is showing blank screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_RES_ID, (int) id);
```

pass image id to your other activity

```
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_RES_ID, mThumbIdsFlowers[position]);
```